# Place $n$ points on hemisphere such that their distance in $\mathcal{R}^3$ is maximal?

Tags: spheres, packing-problem

How to place $n$ points on a unit hemisphere, such that balls of some radius $r$ around those points cover the maximum amount of volume that lies in the region $(x, y, z)$ with $x \geq 0$, $y, z \in \mathcal{R}$, where the balls can't overlap?

First off, I should say that I'm looking for a solution that is *good enough*, not necessarily perfect. My intended goal is constructing a filter bank of $n$ filters with Fourier support centered at the points on the hemisphere and bandwidth $r$.

I basically see two problems that need to be overcome. Most efficient placements (such as the [Fibonacci lattice](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.4540.pdf)

1. Cover the whole sphere, not just a hemisphere.
2. Maximize the *area* each point represents, not its volume.

As far as I can see, adapting the Fibonacci lattice to cover a hemisphere is my best bet, and it will probably involve cutting of the spiral somewhere a distance $r$ above the $(y, z)$-plane, since I really don't care about the frequencies $(x, y, z)$ with $ x < 0$.

I am really curious to hear your ideas.

Comment: Isn't there a third problem in that a perfect packing of balls on the surface of the unit (hemi-)sphere yields a set of spheres which are not necessarily disjoint (they can intersect within the unit (hemi-)sphere? Also, given your description of the application, wouldn't there be a preference for a packing where the uncovered volume was distributed relative uniformly over the hemisphere rather than having a large "hole" somewhere?

Comment: In addition, for problems of this type some knowledge about the size of $n$ is fairly important, especially if you want algorithmic advice. E.g., packing 7 spheres is qualitatively different than packing 7000.